Do there exist $n$ points where any 3-class division guarantees at least 2 points in the same class 1 unit apart.

Is it possible to have a set of points on a plane such that no matter how you divide these points into 3 groups, there will always be at least two points in the same group whose distance on the plane is 1?

I try to solve it like this, but I think it is wrong. Suppose there are $n$ points in the plane. Let positive integer $a$ be the least segment we can have after dividing in to three classes. Let positive integer $b$ be the number of segment that isn't 1. The strategy is finding several points in the plane such that $a>b$. By AM-GM inequality, if $n$ can be written in the form of $3k$, then $a$ occur when three plies each have $k$ points. if $n$ can be written in the form of $3k+1$, then $a$ occur when two plies have $k$ and the other pile have $k+1$ points. if $n$ can be written in the form of $3k+2$, then $a$ occur when two plies have $k+1$ and the other pile have $k$ points. So $a$ can be express as follow.
For  $ n = 3k $:
$a = 3 \binom{k}{2}$
For $ n = 3k + 1 $:
$a = 2 \binom{k}{2} + \binom{k+1}{2}$
For $n = 3k + 2 $:
$a = 2 \binom{k+1}{2} + \binom{k}{2}$
But I couldn't figure out how to solve for $b$.

Welcome to MSE. I'm not familiar with the term "$3$-class division". Can you define it so I could try to help you? Thank you!

Here is the original problem statement:Is it possible to have a set of points on a plane such that no matter how you divide these points into 3 groups, there will always be at least two points in the same group whose distance on the plane is 1?

For $n \ge 7$ it is possible.  In the figure below all segments are intended to have length $1$.  Once you put $A$ in one group, $B$ and $C$ must be in the other two groups, so $D$ must be in the same group as $A$.  Similarly, $D_1$ must be in the same group as $A$ but $D$ and $D_1$ are $1$ unit apart.

